# compare a dataframe with a list and extract the matching rows in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have the main data frame that has 415526 entries (rows), which represents the list of proteins in 51 microbial species. As each protein has a different number of protein domains, the number of columns for each entry is different.

df

```
AC_peg_0686__[locus_tag=Adeh_0688]  Response_reg    Sigma54_activat HTH_8   
AC_peg_0687__[locus_tag=Adeh_0689]  Ribosomal_L31   
AC_peg_0688__[locus_tag=Adeh_0690]  Rho_N   Rho_RNA_bind    ATP-synt_ab 
AC_peg_0689__[locus_tag=Adeh_0691]  No_Domain   
AC_peg_0690__[locus_tag=Adeh_0692]  N_methyl    
AC_peg_0691__[locus_tag=Adeh_0693]  DNA_ligase_aden DNA_ligase_OB   DNA_ligase_ZBD  HHH_2   BRCT    
AC_peg_0692__[locus_tag=Adeh_0694]  Acylphosphatase 
AC_peg_0693__[locus_tag=Adeh_0695]  Radical_SAM DUF2344 
AC_peg_0694__[locus_tag=Adeh_0696]  RNase_E_G   
AC_peg_0695__[locus_tag=Adeh_0697]  Virul_fac_BrkB  
AC_peg_0696__[locus_tag=Adeh_0698]  Bac_DNA_binding 
AC_peg_0697__[locus_tag=Adeh_0699]  FHIPEP  
AC_peg_0698__[locus_tag=Adeh_0700]  Bac_export_2    
AC_peg_0699__[locus_tag=Adeh_0701]  Bac_export_1    
AC_peg_0700__[locus_tag=Adeh_0702]  Bac_export_3    
AC_peg_0701__[locus_tag=Adeh_0703]  FliP    
AC_peg_0702__[locus_tag=Adeh_0704]  FliO
.
.
.
.....and so on....till 415526
```

similarly, I have another file, that has a list of protein domains. it has 38 entries. I have to compare the main data frame with the list and extract the rows that match the entries of the list. my list looks like this

df1

```
Bac_export_1
Bac_export_2
Bac_export_3
Bac_export_4
ChapFlgA
CheC
FHIPEP
Flg_hook
FlgD
FlgD_ig
FlgI
FlgI
FlgM
FlgN
FlhC
FlhD
FlhE
```

I want separate files for each protein domain on the list.

I have tried to compare and intersect functions but they were not fruitful.

```
df3 <- intersect(df$col , df1$col)
```

here is an example of how my final file should look like. this file only has entries that matched with 'MotB_plug' entry from the list.

```
Aliivibrio_salmonicida_LFI1238__peg_0951___VSAL_RS05180 MotB_plug   OmpA
Aliivibrio_wodanis__peg_0687___AWOD_RS03580 MotB_plug   OmpA
Grimontia_hollisae_ATCC_33564__peg_1011___AL542_RS08920 MotB_plug   OmpA
Grimontia_hollisae_ATCC_33564__peg_1828___AL542_RS13325 MotB_plug   OmpA
Paraphotobacterium_marinum_NSCS20N07D__peg_0036___CF386_RS00180 MotB_plug   OmpA
Vibrio_alginolyticus_ATCC_17749__peg_2782___N646_RS14135    MotB_plug   OmpA
Vibrio_alginolyticus_ATCC_17749__peg_3208___N646_RS16270    MotB_plug   OmpA
```

just like the above, there should be different files for each element of the list.

Comment: Please provide samples of you df and your list after passing each of them through ```dput()```

Comment: its not working

Comment: What is the return from ```dput(df)```?

Comment: `````
Label = c("", "A2M", "A2M_BRD", ..............    "TSP_3", "UnbV_ASPIC", "Vault_3", "VCBS", "WD40", "WG_beta_rep", 
    "YwqJ-deaminase", "zf-C4_Topoisom"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-415546L))
````````
it is showing all the values of columns

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BBT31zcsXGP9-N2gRoJ5wdWkHrq6LT1r?usp=sharing

these are my files.

Comment: Great! Can you then please make a small sample of, say, 20 rows, pass it through ```dput```, and then add it to the post?